# Cannot login to php page when sql column type is changed from TEXT to varchar

Tags: php, mysql

my log in page used to work correctly when the column type for password was TEXT.
I have updated the table contents and used to sql password function on the passwords but now the format is varchar and the page will not authenticate.

below is the code in question:

```
<main>
            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    include 'databaselogin.php';

                    $username = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['username']));
                    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $username);
                    $password = $_POST['password'];

                    $sql = "SELECT *
                            FROM teams
                            WHERE name = '$username'";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

                    if($result->num_rows == 1){
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        $hash = $row["password"];

                        if(password_verify($password,$hash)){
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["name"];

                            header("Location: http://www.josephade.com/fyp/dashboard.php");
                            die();
                        }
                    }else{
                        //Show error incorrect password
                        include 'error.php';
                    }

                    mysqli_close($mysqli);
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Did the hash change in the column(s) when you changed it? Did TEXT have a length as does your VARCHAR and long enough for it?

Comment: Make sure the column content wasn't truncated

Comment: @Fred-ii- Text did not have a length but im sure VARCHAR length ive used is long enough.

Comment: @AlexM I do not think so. I Have even tried using a simple password in plaintext such as 12345 and the page will still not progress

Comment: *Hm...*, you may have to rebuild your hashes then. As mentioned by Alex M, is the column truncated at all?

Comment: Use orm or atleast pdo. Just var_export $has and $password and compare them yourself. It's clearly an error in the comparison.

Comment: When you say you used the SQL password function, do you mean that in addition to changing the column type you run an update that used the  MySQL `PASSWORD` function to hash the passwords?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I Just rebuilt them all and it is working again. something must have gone wrong along the line.

Comment: That's great Joe, glad to hear my comment helped to solve it for you; *cheers!*

Comment: Somebody post the answer so this can be closed.

Comment: @Joe Someone suggested ^ to post an answer. What do you want to do with this? It should probably be deleted, since my comment to you helped you solve it. As to the actual reason why it would do that, I would need to research it to provide a true answer.

Comment: @Joe I found something in the MySQL documentation, and have posted an answer for you below, should you choose to accept it as correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didnt know how to post the anwer

Comment: Hi Joe. Did the one I posted below in fact offer a solution?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes it did, I believe that was the issue I encountered and your answer seems to explain the reasoning behind it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very much welcome Joe and I'm glad it was resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in the MySQL documentation for `BLOB` and `TEXT` which are both related.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html

**11.4.3 The BLOB and TEXT Types**

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a BLOB or TEXT column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.

which would explain the data loss.

- Therefore, a total rebuild is required to go from TEXT to VARCHAR, as mentioned in my comment:

> *"you may have to rebuild your hashes then"*

---

Another link I found in regards to this:

- http://nicj.net/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance/

Partial retrieval from that page:

> Starting with MySQL 5.0.3, the maximum field length for VARCHAR fields was increased from 255 characters to 65,535 characters.  This is good news, as VARCHAR fields, as opposed to TEXT fields, are stored in-row for the MyISAM storage engine (InnoDB has different characteristics).  TEXT and BLOB fields are not stored in-row — they require a separate lookup (and a potential disk read) if their column is included in a SELECT clause.  Additionally, the inclusion of a TEXT or BLOB column in any sort will force the sort to use a disk-based temporary table, as the MEMORY (HEAP) storage engine, which is used for temporary tables, requires.
>
> Thus, the benefits of using a VARCHAR field instead of TEXT for columns between 255 and 65k characters seem obvious at first glance in some scenarios: potentially less disk reads (for queries including the column, as there is no out-of-row data) and less writes (for queries with sorts including the column).